# Looking for sample code to test IoT Hub DM API

Tags: azure, iot

Where can I find sample code for implementing the Azure IoT Hub Device Management features? Looking at https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks there doesn't seem to be any samples on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Over the course of the last hour, you've asked three off-topic questions, running your way towards a question ban. You don't want that. Please take the time to read the [tour], visit the help center and especially [ask]. Asking for off-site resources is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are at the right repo but the DM additions are currently in a different branch called 'dmpreview'.

Select this on Github and you will see in the csharp samples a new project in the 'GetStartedWithIoTHubDM' folder. This sample goes through the various features currently available (creating devices, reading device twins etc.)